# Alternatives to "I lived the wrong way"?

Tags: synonyms

If someone has realized that he made a wrong decision in life or has had the wrong beliefs for a long time, he might say *I lived the wrong way*. What are alternative ways of phrasing this?

It doesn't need to be religious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

> I need to turn over a new leaf.

Answer (score 3):

Since this is a common sentiment within Christianity (and you did mention *belief*) here's some synonymous phrases you might hear in that context:

> I was blind but now I see.
>   I was lost but now am found.
>     I strayed
>   from the straight and narrow.
>      I strayed from the path of righteousness.
>   I am a prodigal son, returning home.

Answer (score 0):

> Forgive me Father, for I have
>   sinned...

That's a very common line, haha :)

But normally, I would just say, "I made a wrong move" if I felt I made a bad decision.

Answer (score 0):

People often say that they have *reformed* from something; e.g. "I am a *reformed* alcoholic".